# Why does file/open and command tool refer to different locations for c:\windows\system32\drivers in Windows XP 64?

Tags: windows-xp

Try the following experiment at your leasure in a Windows XP 64 box:

1. Run Internet explorer, non-64bit version, or any other 32-bit program.
2. Do file/open and browse to `c:\windows\system32\drivers` . Note that there are (typically) no files in this directory.
3. Open a command shell with Start/Run/cmd and do `dir c:\windows\system32\drivers`.

The result is that you see a different set of files. That is, the same path refers to two different physical locations on the hard disk! What is the explanation for this? How can a 32-bit program (e.g. bash) refer to the "real" `c:\windows\system32\drivers` directory?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the right of the snip of the IE file open Dialog. What is the files filter type?

[image]

By default it's **Web Documents** and thus now files displayed because there are no web documents in the Sys32 Drivers folder.

If I change the filter to All Files

[image]

Comment: Right, I should have noted that you need to change to "All files", but you will still not show the same files as in c:\windows\system32\Drivers. Even in your screenshot you have 6 files in there. From `cmd` you will see hundreds of files.